# iOS: Handle invalid session in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, session, delegates

I am currently working on an iOS app that requires authentication. I have trouble transitioning to the login view when the invalid session occurred.

My idea to handle this is by notifying the app delegate that the session has became invalid; the app delegate will then take the user to the login screen.

In my current view controller, I have this code logic to detect the invalid session:

```
if (responseCode == INVALID_AUTHORIZATION) {
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
    [appdelegate invalidateSession];
    return;
}
```

In my app delegate, I handle the invalid authorization by taking the user to the root controller.

```
- (void) invalidateSession {
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

*Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .*

*Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.*

Any thought on what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Inside what method is your first snippet?

Comment: in one of my view controllers. this is after i got the network result back from my data manager.

Comment: passing NO doesn't fix the problem. i'll poke around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't implement the pop - push transitions in AppDelegate because you can't be sure if the previous transition has completed before popping the view controller - which causes the issue mentioned above.

In case you have to check the session in many screens, I suggest implementing a "super" view controller that has a method named `checkSession` where you do the check and pop the view controller when necessary. This method should be called in `viewDidAppear` just so you can make sure no transition is incomplete by the time you call `popToRootViewController`. Then you'll need to make all the view controllers that requires authenticating subclass that super view controller and you're good to go. I hope this is useful for you.

P.s: Since you have to complete displaying the views before checking session, I think maybe a popup mentioning an expired session would be neat for your UI.

Comment: yes, popping the view before viewDidAppear was called is a problem. I've fixed it using your approach. Thanks!